# Centre Multiple Responsive Divs Using CSS / JQUERY / HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I'm new to html and css and I'm trying to create a website, part of the code is here:

**HTML**

```
<div class="apoios">
<h7>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Apoios</h7>
<br>
<div class="thunnb">
    <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>
(...)
<div class="thunnb">
    <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.thunnb {
float: left;
padding: 10px;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
}
.apoios img {
    border:1px solid #;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
h7 {
    font-size:22px !important;
    font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    margin-bottom:6px !important;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.apoio {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**JSFIDDLE** - https://jsfiddle.net/wpswddnq/

I want to centre the "thunnb" divs while maintaining it responsive. Basically it must stay centred (with the most possible images in the same row) all the time while the user is adapting the window.

> Note: This is for a block in Drupal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Change** `float: left;` to `display: inline-block;` in `thunnb` class.

**E.g.**

```
.thunnb {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

**Then** add `text-align: center;` in `apoios` class.

**E.g.**

```
.apoios {
    text-align: center;
}
```

You can now remove the `display: inline-block;` in `apoios` class.

**Here's the [JsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/albertonaperijr/wpswddnq/1/).**

Hope it helps.

Comment: @AlbertoI.N.J. Hey, I am having the same problem with this: [https://jsfiddle.net/nuvkmsx2/](https://jsfiddle.net/nuvkmsx2/)
I want to keep the images responsive and maintaining the aspect ratio, but I want them to be centred. I have tried what you said before but it does not seem to be working!

Comment: @magamig I just checked your **jsfiddle** link. **First,** you didn't assign the `noticias` class as class but instead you assigned it as a `tag`. You need to add `.` to declare it as class. **E.g.** `.noticias`. **Second,** the spelling of your `center` is `centre` which is not a valid `text-align` property value. I updated your **jsfiddle**. Here's the link: https://jsfiddle.net/albertonaperijr/nuvkmsx2/1/. Hope it helps.

Comment: @AlbertoI.N.J. Is there any way to reduce the space between the left and the right collumns? than you again for your help!

Comment: @megamig So, you want to stretch the images?

Comment: @AlbertoI.N.J. Nevermind, in the drupal block it worked the way it was supposed to! Thank you again and sorry dor my begginer errors :p

Comment: @megamig No problem. All people do mistakes. I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try locking the size of the grid in a div, then forcing its position to stay absolute center with jQuery:

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event) {
    resize();
}, false);

function resize() {
    var lhalf = ($(window).width() - 700) / 2;
    var thalf = ($(window).height() - 550) / 2;
    $('.apoios').css('left', lhalf);
    $('.apoios').css('top', thalf);
}

resize();
```

```css
.thunnb {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
.apoios img {
    border:1px solid #;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
h7 {
    font-size:22px !important;
    font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    margin-bottom:6px !important;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.apoios {
    position: absolute;
    height: 550px;
    width: 700px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="apoios">
    <h7>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Apoios</h7>
    <br>
    <div class="thunnb">
        <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
    </div>
    <div class="thunnb">
        <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
    </div>
    <div class="thunnb">
        <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
    </div>
    <div class="thunnb">
        <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
    </div>
    <div class="thunnb">
        <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
    </div>
    <div class="thunnb">
        <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
    </div>
    <div class="thunnb">
        <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
    </div>
    <div class="thunnb">
        <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
    </div>
    <div class="thunnb">
        <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
    </div>
    <div class="thunnb">
        <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
    </div>
    <div class="thunnb">
        <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
    </div>
    <div class="thunnb">
        <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it stops being responsive, and the answer from Alberto is working! thank you anyway