# responsive grid of tiles evenly spaced - Is it possible with pure css ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ive got a grid that has boxes in it, each box is the same size and has the same markup.

What im trying todo is have the boxes fill the full width of the page with an even gap between them. The idea is that if the browser window moves the box items will restack.

Ive looked into various ways of doing this including using the grid system from bootstrap 3, as well as from [HERE](http://responsivegridsystem.com)

Ive also looked into using a JS plugin for this like Masonry, which although would work seems a bit overkill as all the tile sizes are the same.

At the moment ive got it almost working here : http://jsfiddle.net/3xshcn7p/

The only issue with this current approach is that if the browser window is <719px but >481 it will display only 2 of the boxs and leave a big blank space down the right hand side.

The same issue occurs between all of the boxes when the screen is not big enough for the next number of boxes per row up.

Any ideas if this is achievable purely using `css` or would it have to use `js` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `flexbox` approach for the solution.

`justify-content: space-around` is used if the even space is needed *around all the elements* of the layout.

`justify-content: space-between` is needed for even space *in between the elements* of the layout.

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  background: #336633;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  background: white;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<!--wrapper-->
```

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `text-align: center;` to the `body` element then change `float: left;` to `display: inline-block;`.

**E.g.**

```
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height:100%;
    background: #336633;
    text-align: center;
}

.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    background: white;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

**Here's the [JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/albertonaperijr/3xshcn7p/1/).**

**Update:** I also answered a similar question. [Centre Multiple Responsive Divs Using CSS / JQUERY / HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31151365/centre-multiple-responsive-divs-using-css-jquery-html/31151478#31151478)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox can do this,

[**Jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3xshcn7p/4/)

```
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height:100%;
    background: #336633;
}
.wrapper {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    justify-content:space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    background: white;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fill the whole width, then 1. you keep the .box width fixed at 200px, and then you can just center, or 2. you give them a flexible width.
Here one more solution, with flexible width and flexible margins, using media queries.

```
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height:100%;
    background: #336633;
}

.box {
    height: 250px;
    background: white;
    float: left;
    /*margin: 20px;*/
    margin: 2%;
    width: 100%;
}

/* 50% - ( 2 * 2% margins ), etc */
@media (min-width: 240px) { .box { width: 46%; } }
@media (min-width: 480px) { .box { width: 29%; } }
@media (min-width: 720px) { .box { width: 21%; } }
@media (min-width: 960px) {     
    /* Now we set margin to 1%, so .box width is 20% - (2 * 1% margins) */
    .box { width: 18%; } 
    .box { margin: 1%; }
} 
@media (min-width: 1200px) { .box { width: 14.666%; } }
@media (min-width: 1440px) { .box { width: 12.285%; } }
@media (min-width: 1680px) { .box { width: 10.5%; } }
@media (min-width: 1920px) { 
    .box { width: 10.111%; }
    .box { margin: 0.5%; }
}

@media (min-width: 2160px) { .box { width: 9%; } }
/* and just go further if you want more columns */

/* media queries if you want fixed margin of 20px on each side
@media (min-width: 240px) { .box { width: calc(50% - 40px); } }
@media (min-width: 480px) { .box { width: calc(33% - 40px); } }
@media (min-width: 720px) { .box { width: calc(25% - 40px); } }
and so on
*/
```

Comment: Thanks its a good approach, but the only issue i can see with it is that on a larger screen it donst scale to more than 4 boxes per line., ive tried a couple of things, but coulnt get any of them to work. Ive made a jsfiddle with your example here - http://jsfiddle.net/3xshcn7p/6/

Comment: @sam, you can add as many steps as you need (see edit, up to 10 columns). But of course it's right, it stops somewhere. But there is also a time when we look at a bigger screen from bigger distance and it may be better if the boxes also become bigger. It will depend on your use case. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xshcn7p/7/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative values for the width and margin of those boxes. For example `width: 30%`/`width: 30vw;`.

```
.box {
    width: 30vw;
    margin: 1vw;
    height: 250px;
    background: white;
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3xshcn7p/3/

Answer (score 0):

I would use css column. Like so :

```
article {
          columns: 2 200px;
       column-gap: 4em;
      column-rule: 1px dotted #ddd;
}
```

If the window gets smaller, the number of columns is reduced. Here's the CodePen of css-tricks.com

http://codepen.io/katydecorah/pen/0cef950304c03248935b3b821e8b7cec